# Running a Job in grails to fetch remote table data on every 15 minutes

Tags: grails, plugins, quartz-scheduler

I have a remote table which i am accessing thru web service.Now i have a requirement to count for a phone number entry which changes very 15 minute.
Trying to use Grails quartz1.0 plug in.Installed and created a job.
 but not sure how to set to execute the job every 15 min. Sample code to test is here-

```
 class CountJob {
  static triggerNow = {
 // simple repeatCount: 10 // execute job once in 15 minutes
//def startDelay = 60000
    //def timeout = 10000000      
//def group = "MyGroup"
}

def execute() {
    println "run job!!"
 }  
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want it to repeat every 15 minutes and not a complicated cron expression, you can replace your `triggerNow` section with:

```
static triggers = {
    // execute job once every 15 minutes. 1000 * 60 * 15 millis
    simple repeatInterval: 900000l 
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply.I need to run a service every 15 minute.but above code only executed once. can we do something so that it executes every 15 min ,all day long.

Comment: If you change the repeat interval to `5000l` does it repeat every 5 seconds?

Comment: nope. executed only once.I changed - simple repeatInterval:  5000l

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the plugin docs for [Scheduling a Cron Job](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html). **Something like below** is what you can use:

```
class CountJob {
    static triggers = {
      cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0/15 * * * ?"
    }

    def execute() {
        println "run job!!"
     }  
}
```

To put more light on how the cron expressions are created in Quartz, visit this [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) tutorial page.

Comment: By "doesn't work" do you mean you get an error, or it just never runs?   @dmahapatro's answer is exactly how you would run a job every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Kelly. I have mentioned all the resources on how to get a desired cron expression. If `0 0/15 0 * * ?` does not work, refer the doc on Quartz Scheduler word by word and try to implement according to your need. As a matter of fact, I updated my answer to fit your use case. Note:- 0 in cron expression is beginning of a minute/hour/second, * is a wild card entry.

Comment: before posting this question i have gone thru the doc.tried well. dmahapatro ,i mean the above code never get executed after first time. is'nt it suppose to execute on every 15 mins?

Comment: My dear friend, I had to wait for 30 mins to show you [my actual test results](http://pastebin.com/09P0Gz07).

Comment: I have made a minor change to your code and it worked for me as expected.used 0 */15 * * * ?   instead of 0 0/15 * * * ?. thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @sana M glad I was of some help.

Comment: @sana wasn't cron job helpful?